# How to Delete All Items From SQLite in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-delete

I would like to make an app where the user clicks a button, and the SQLite database is cleared. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
db.delete(TABLE_NAME, null, null);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The delete method returns a value.  What value are you getting?

Comment: Does deleting records from the table using compileStatement work?

Comment: You could delete the `database.sqlite` and recreate the structure afterwards.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Your delete() call is correct. Did you get writable database? Here is example of method using delete:

```
/**
 * Remove all users and groups from database.
 */
public void removeAll()
{
    // db.delete(String tableName, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs);
    // If whereClause is null, it will delete all rows.
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase(); // helper is object extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    db.delete(DatabaseHelper.TAB_USERS, null, null);
    db.delete(DatabaseHelper.TAB_USERS_GROUP, null, null);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I did use `getWritableDatabase()`.

Comment: We should also close the db no?

Answer (score 17):

db.delete(TABLE_NAME, null, null); is the correct syntax to delete all rows in a table. But I think you would have given table name directly without enclosing it in double-quotes. Try like this

```
db.delete("TABLE_NAME", null, null);
```

It might help :)

Answer (score 4):

Use This Code for clear all database content

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'", null);
String tableName="";
  if (c.moveToFirst()) {

      while ( !c.isAfterLast() ) {

          tableName = c.getString( c.getColumnIndex("name"));
          if(!tableName.equals('android_metadata')){
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE '"+tableName+"'");
          }
          c.moveToNext();
      }
  }

c.close();
```

Comment: This seems to be a pretty good solution to delete all table names, although, it does not take into account triggers/indexes.

Comment: There is a table called `sqlite_sequence` that should not be removed either.

Answer (score 3):

Actually another way I did it was to `DROP` the tables and then just call the `onCreate` method for the `SQLiteDatabase`. I don't know which is most a efficient `Delete` or `Drop` because I haven't really dug deep into how efficient each method is but it works great for me because in my initial database I have some default values set and so when I call the `onCreate` method for the database I have some `PUT` methods there also.  This saves code replication. ( instead of doing the delete and then the puts I get a multi purpose out of my `onCreate` function).

I call it `reset`. So you'd just have to do `db.reset()` and then the default values are added in the `onCreate` after you make your tables.

```
public void reset () throws SQLException {
    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase ();
    db.execSQL ("drop table "+TABLE_NAME);
    db.close ();
    this.DBHelper.onCreate (this.db);
}
```

Comment: What if I had multiple tables? I would call exeSQL drop table ___ multiple times?

Answer (score 2):

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); //get database
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM tablename"); //delete all rows in a table
db.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could try when developing on a device:

settings>>applications>>(your application name)>>Storage>> clear cache and clear data

by clearing the application data and the application cache, you also wipe the sql database.

Answer (score 1):

use this code:

```
public void deleteAll()
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("delete from "+ TABLE_NAME);
    db.close();
}
```

you can add it DatabaseHandler class, this is full source code:

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// All Static variables
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "OffLineMessagesClient";

// Contacts table name
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "messages_client";

// Contacts Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ENTITY_ID = "entity_id";
private static final String KEY_MESSAGE = "message";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
            + KEY_ENTITY_ID + " INTEGER,"
            + KEY_MESSAGE + " TEXT"
            +  ")";

    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion,
                      int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}

public void deleteAll()
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("delete from "+ TABLE_NAME);
    db.close();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for me classical mysql statement:

```
SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = context.openOrCreateDatabase(Database.DATABASE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null, null);
sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + tableName1);
sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + tableName2);
sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + tableName3);
sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + tableName4);
```

worked perfectly. good luck :)
ps.: without start/endtransaction or closeDatabase…

Answer (score 0):

this work for me:

```
 public void removeAll()
{

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); 
    db.delete(TABLE_NAME, null, null);
    db.close();



}
```