# Database clear each time my application runs

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

Does anyone know how to reset the database everytime my application executes in real device ?

I currently have this code but it does not work...

```
public void doDBCheck()
    {
        try{
                File file = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath());
                file.delete();
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            }
        }
```

Any solutions ?

Comment: in emulator or real device?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406067/how-to-delete-sqlite-database-from-android-programmatically

Comment: where will I put that piece of code?

Comment: on your main activity initialization

Comment: You'd write that snippet of code where you actually want to delete the database.

Comment: When you say reset the db do you mean Delete the database file itself OR clear the database of all records?

Comment: clear the database of all records... I'll put in on my onCreate() in MainActivity

Comment: Then you want a different answer. Wait let me write it for you.

Comment: @Jigar the code doesn't also work..

Comment: Did you try this: [How to Delete All Items From SQLite in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5683940/2558882).

Answer (score 0):

```
public void clearDatabase()
{
SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
db.delete({tablename},null,null) // write this line for each table in your db.
}
```