# Creation of databases at run time in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, dataprovider

I am using a `DataProvider` for my app to handle CRUD operations. Now the `DataProvider` is using an `SQLiteOpenHelper` nested inner class. All definitions of the CRUD operations are defined inside the `DataProvider` itself and the `SQLiteOpenHelper` class is responsible for creation of database, say **abc.db** and defining two tables say **table1** and **table2**.  Now, when a user logs in to the app, the database is created (obviously if not exists) and the data for the user is displayed by using `ContentResolver` queries and `CursorLoader` for loading into lists. This part I have achieved.

The problem arises in a multi-user scenario. Suppose a user decides to logout and login with another account or register for a new account, as the data for the previous user is retained, the previous data is also loaded into the `ListView` and/or other views fetching data from the database. According to my logic, this can be prevented by creating new database instances for each new user on the same device. But since the `ContentProvider` initialises the database prior to Activity's `onCreate()`, I find this hard to achieve. Any idea on how it can be implemented?

Comment: Can't you have a field in the table of your database named USER_ID and when you load the data see the logged user's USER_ID and perform a `select your_columns from your_table where USER_ID=this_users_id` ?

Comment: Cant you delete the database when the first user logs out? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683840/how-to-delete-all-items-from-sqlite-in-android and if you have user data as Shared Preferences, you can clear that also. Just google it :)

Comment: @GeorgeD Yes obviously I can, but that means an extra overhead of checking for every single query and an unwanted column for every field. This solution I consider to be last resort.

Comment: @edwinj No unfortunately I can't, rather shouldn't. What if he logs out by mistake or manages multiple accounts. And regrading sharedpreferences, I am already using it for storing info of currently logged in users because for every POST request I make, the username has to be sent along. I am clearing the sharedpreferences once he logs out and replacing new credentials for the newly logged in user.

Comment: I do not think including a `where` statement could add much overhead to the whole process, quite the opposite happens when you lower your scope. You can also create different tables for different users. Or if you do not wish to do anything at the database level you can check the cursor and if it contains values you do not want you drop them.

Comment: I don't think, I understand your question. So when the user logs out shouldn't you remove the data of that user or do you mean when the user changes the account or ads a new account? If you mean the second case, then you could have a user db where there should be an id column and you could have a string in shared prefs called current_user_id and this should change when user changes account.. then each of your query could be like SELECT your_data FROM table1 WHERE id=current_user_id.. basically what @GeorgeD said before.

Comment: I agree that's a valid solution, but is that the ONLY solution? Isn't dynamic database creation possible in Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I find no other alternative means so do so, I believe maintaining a `user_id` column is the only way to ensure multi-user usability without interference. I have implemented the same and added an additional `WHERE` clause to all querues using `user_id=?` and the currently logged in user as the `user_id` argument. The idea of creating databases at run time, even if possible, may not be necessary atleast for my problem statement.