# Data is repeating twice when i open my app

Tags: android, listview

I have a API which responds in `JSON`. When I clicked a button I am comfortably parse the JSON and implement it in the `ListView`. The problem is When I open my app 
again the data comes again in `ListView`.
Following is my code-

**Monday.java:**

```
package com.example.reema.datatab2;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by reema on 30-Jan-17.
 */
public class Monday extends Fragment {
    private String TAG = Monday.class.getSimpleName();
    DatabaseHandler databaseHandler;
    static boolean isDataLoaded = false;

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mondayList;

    ListView listview;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.monday,container,false);
        mondayList= new ArrayList<>();
        listview =(ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.lstmonday);
        new GetContacts().execute();
        return v;
    }


    class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            databaseHandler = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
            String url = "My link here";
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);
            Log.e(TAG, "Responce from url:" + jsonStr);


            if(isDataLoaded == false) {
                if (jsonStr != null) {

                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);


                        JSONArray Monday = jsonObj.getJSONArray("Monday");


                        for (int i = 0; i < Monday.length(); i++) {


                            JSONObject c = Monday.getJSONObject(i);

                            String SubjectName = c.getString("SubjectName");
                            String StandardName;
                            if (c.isNull("StandardName")) {
                                StandardName = null;
                            } else {
                                StandardName = c.getString("StandardName");
                            }


                            String DivisionName;
                            if (c.isNull("DivisionName")) {
                                DivisionName = null;
                            } else {
                                DivisionName = c.getString("DivisionName");
                            }
                            String StartTime = c.getString("StartTime");
                            String EndTime = c.getString("EndTime");

                            String LectureNoId;
                            if (c.isNull("DivisionName") && (c.isNull("StandardName"))) {
                                LectureNoId = null;
                            } else {
                                LectureNoId = c.getString("LectureNoId");
                            }

                            databaseHandler.addMonday(new People(LectureNoId, SubjectName, StandardName, DivisionName, StartTime, EndTime));
                    /*    HashMap<String, String> monday = new HashMap<>();
                        monday.put("LectureNoId",LectureNoId);
                        monday.put("SubjectName", SubjectName);
                        monday.put("StandardName", StandardName);
                        monday.put("DivisionName", DivisionName);
                        monday.put("StartTime", StartTime);
                        monday.put("EndTime", EndTime);

                        mondayList.add(monday);*/

                        }
                    } catch (final JSONException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                        .show();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
                 else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    });

                }


            return null;
        }
        protected void onPreExecute () {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
               pDialog.show();

        }
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();



            List<People>monday = databaseHandler.getAllMonday();
            for(People p : monday) {

                HashMap<String, String> mondayhash = new HashMap<>();
                mondayhash.put("LectureNoId",p.getLectureNoId());
                mondayhash.put("SubjectName", p.getSubjectName());
                mondayhash.put("StandardName", p.getStandardName());
                mondayhash.put("DivisionName", p.getDivisionName());
                mondayhash.put("StartTime", p.getStartTime());
                mondayhash.put("EndTime", p.getEndTime());

                mondayList.add(mondayhash);
            }

            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    getActivity(), mondayList,
                    R.layout.custom_list, new String[]{"SubjectName", "StandardName",
                    "DivisionName","StartTime","EndTime"}, new int[]{R.id.SubjectName,
                    R.id.StandardName, R.id.DivisionName,R.id.StartTime,R.id.EndTime});
            isDataLoaded=true;
            databaseHandler.deleteMonday();
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);

        }


    }

}
```

**Databasehandler.java:**

```
package com.example.reema.datatab2;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mondayManager";
    private static final String Monday = "monday";



    private static final String LectureNoId = "LectureNoId";
    private static final String SubjectName = "SubjectName";
    private static final String StandardName = "StandardName";
    private static final String DivisionName = "DivisionName";
    private static final String StartTime = "StartTime";
    private static final String EndTime = "EndTime";


    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String monday = "CREATE TABLE " + Monday + "(" + LectureNoId + " TEXT,"
                + SubjectName + " TEXT," + StandardName + " TEXT," + DivisionName + " TEXT," + StartTime + " TEXT,"
                + EndTime + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(monday);




    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Monday ");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Tuesday" );
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Wensday" );
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS  Thursday");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS  Friday");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS  Saturday");



        onCreate(db);
    }
    public void addMonday(People contact) {

        if (!SearchExistingLectureID(contact.getLectureNoId(), Monday)) {

          SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(LectureNoId, contact.getLectureNoId());
            values.put(SubjectName, contact.getSubjectName());
            values.put(StandardName, contact.getStandardName());
            values.put(DivisionName, contact.getDivisionName());
            values.put(StartTime, contact.getStartTime());
            values.put(EndTime, contact.getEndTime());


            db.insert(Monday, null, values);
            Log.d("db", "insert called");
            db.close();

        }
    }
void deleteMonday()
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("delet from Monday");
}



    public Boolean SearchExistingLectureID(String LectureID, String Table)
    {
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + Table + " where LectureNoId = "  +LectureID;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        Boolean retValue = false;
        //there is a chance of exceptoin if the lectureid is not found in db.
        try {
            if (cursor.getCount()>0 && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                String val =  cursor.getString(1);

                retValue = true;
            }
        }catch (Exception ex){
            Log.d("error", ex.getMessage());
        }
        return  retValue;
    }

    public List<People> getAllMonday() {
        List<People> MondayList = new ArrayList<People>();

        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + Monday;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

            do {
                People contact = new People(cursor.getString(0),cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), cursor.getString(5));
                contact.setLectureNoId(cursor.getString(0));
                contact.setSubjectName(cursor.getString(1));
                contact.setStandardName(cursor.getString(2));
                contact.setDivisionName(cursor.getString(3));
                contact.setStartTime(cursor.getString(4));
                contact.setEndTime(cursor.getString(5));

                MondayList.add(contact);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }


        return MondayList;

    }



   }
```

Comment: clear your list everytime.

Comment: Can you share your Activity class which hosts the Fragment?

Comment: just add mondayList.clear(); below this line  if (jsonStr != null) {

Comment: You are adding data each time you get response. You should use replace instead of add

Comment: just try clearing the mondayList before adding items to it

Comment: I think before calling the AsyncTask execute() method, you should first check whether you have data in the database, if yes simply populate the list from there else you can make the network call.

Comment: Every time you making call to your webService, you are adding all the data to the database.
Update the database entries everytime making call to webService instead of adding, which is the cause of duplicate entry in your database.

Comment: That is way, way too much code to debug. Please make a minimal reproduction of your problem.

Answer (score 2):

### Check Table rows No

```
     if(databaseHandler.getRows()==0)
     {
        new GetContacts().execute(); //Calling
        databaseHandler.addMethod();
     }
    else
    {

    }
```

**Method**

```
public int getRows()
{
    String countQuery = "SELECT * FROM your_table_name";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    int cnt = cursor.getCount();
    cursor.close();
    return cnt;
}
```

Comment: Since you are assigning the mondayList to a new ArrayList<>(), wouldn't this list be empty already?

Comment: When you are creating a new object of arrayList, why do you have to clear it right away ?

Answer (score 0):

add below code to your `DatabaseHandler`

**Database Clearing method**:

```
public void removeAll()
{

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); // helper is object extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    db.delete(DatabaseHelper.TAB_USERS, null, null);
    db.delete(DatabaseHelper.TAB_USERS_GROUP, null, null);
}
```

**Call this**

`databaseHandler.removeAll();`  before

```
databaseHandler.addMonday(new People(LectureNoId, SubjectName, StandardName, DivisionName, StartTime, EndTime));
```

in your `GetContacts` AsyncTask.

> It is because you are duplicating your database by doing same data to the database.

Credits: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5683940/5962715).

Answer (score -1):

```
List<People>monday = databaseHandler.getAllMonday();
monday.clear;
for(People p : monday) {}
```

try this i think you should clear array

Comment: If you anyway clear the array, what is the point of getting the list from the database? SImply use new ArrayList<>()

Comment: so all time before entering the loop. so we get correct number of data

Comment: Your list is empty! What will you iterate over? You wont see anything in this case!

Comment: I tried this but my whole listview gets cleared.I want listview to show data once and then again it must not get repeated.